# ExpressJs perform MySQL select query with ? parameters

Tags: mysql, express

I'm new in the use ExpressJs, I created my own project to train myself. I would like to do a search bar so perform a select query with MySQL.

Here's my code :

```
let query = req.params.q;

console.log(query);

//var sql = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE movie_title like '%" + query + "%' OR movie_originalTitle like '%"+ query+"%'";

var sql = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE movie_originalTitle like ? OR movie_title like ?";
var values = [
    ['%' + query + '%', '%' + query + '%']
];

console.log(values[0]);

connection.query(sql, [values], (err, result, fields) => {
    console.log(sql);
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    };

    JSON.stringify(result);
    res.send({ movies: result });
});
```

I would like to do it with '?' parameter. I succeed to do it with one '?' but everytime I try to add the second parameter I got a MySQL Error

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

I don't know why the second '?' parameter throws me an error ...

Do I miss something ? Can anyone help me ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen elsewhere, the second parameter should be an array containing the query parameters.  You are passing this:

```
[values]
```

but `values` is already an array.  Can you try passing `values` directly:

```
connection.query(sql, values, (err, result, fields) => {
    console.log(sql);
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    };

    JSON.stringify(result);
    res.send({ movies: result });
});
```

Comment: Thank you that was my mistake ! It works perfect now  !